# how to calculate mode value of paired numbers?

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, statistics, arithmetic-expressions

My Excel spreadsheet contains 500 coordinate points from a 2D space. I want to find the mode value of these 500 coordinate points. The estimation of mode value of any set of numbers is pretty simple. It's simply the highly repeated number among the set of numbers. In excel:

```
=MODE (A1:A10)
```

yields mode of data from A1 to A10.
However, a coordinate point is a pair of x and y coordinate. Calculating mode value of x and y coordinate individually may cause an error because individual x coordinate might be paired with many y coordinates and vice-versa. Is there any formula in excel to obtain mode value of paired numbers such as 2D coordinate points?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple solution for this problem. Best you can do is split the plot into sections and calculate the coordinate density of each section. The section with the highest number of points is your section of interest. You might take the mid-point coordinates of that section as the mode.

Comment: Problems arise when multiple sections share the same count, how would you determine which section is the one that is supposed to win?

Comment: In my application, I need a representative coordinate among highly dense coordinate points. So, I'm planning to calculate mode at first and remove all the points similar to the mode. I will repeat this four/ five-times such that I can get four/five representative points from all the 500 points which are scattered in the 2D space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a helper column to convert the coordinate pairs to a single number and then use MODE on the helper column. 
The helper column formula would be something like =A5*100000+B5 where the 100000 is a large enough number to elevate the significant digits of the first coordinate beyond the significant digits of the second coordinate.

Comment: Wouldn't that make the values in column A more important than the values in B?

Comment: No, it doesn't. If x coordinate is 2.3 and y coordinate is 4.2, after the above-mentioned mathematical operation, it becomes 230004.2. Hence by this trick, we are able to combine (x,y) coordinate as a single number. The mode value of a set of numbers can be calculated easily and the actual (x,y) coordinate can be obtained by the reversed arithmetic operation.